# Converting Java program to applet

Tags: java, deployment, applet

So I have a pretty basic Java app I have been writing in Eclipse.
I now have realized somewhat late that I want this to run as an applet on my website.

How do I setup `JApplet`? (assuming this is what I need to use)
Is there any "quick fixes" for assuring that the app will be able to be used as an applet?

Comment: Rather than convert to an applet, launch the app. from a link  using **[Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/28410-application-to-japplet-and-reverse/

It was the first item in a Google Search, so next time look there first.